# How many characteristics is a random surface unirational in?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Suppose I have a surface $X$ defined over $\mathbb{Z}$. I am interested in the set $S_X$ of primes $p$ such that $X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p}$ is unirational. If I choose a "random" surface I would expect that $S_X$ is empty. Can we make this precise?

As Remy suggested, if $X = E_1 \times E_2$ where $E_1, E_2$ are elliptic curves whose primes of bad reduction are disjoint then $S_X = \varnothing$ because $X$ dominates $E_i$ of of which is not rational in each characteristic.

Furthermore, if we assume that $S$ is nonempty, how many elements will $S_X$ have on average? Should we expect $S_X$ to be infinite? What do we expect its density to be?

For example, if $X$ dominates a curve $C \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ of positive genus then $S_X$ is contained in the locus of singular fibers of $C$ and thus is finite.

However, for Fermat surfaces of degree $q$ (suppose $q$ is prime), we know that $S_X$ is always infinite with density $1 - 2^{-\nu_2(q-1)}$. So for a random Fermat surface, the density of $S_X$ seems to approach $1$. Precisely, the limit of the probability that $1 - \delta(S) < \varepsilon$ for a Fermat surface of degree < $n$ is $1$ for any $\varepsilon$.

What should we expect for a "general" surface?

Comment: If $X$ is the Kummer surface of the square of an elliptic curve without CM, then I think $S_X$ is infinite and of density zero by Elkies' theorem (and assuming Artin's conjecture for the reductions of $X$).

Comment: I would guess (based on no good evidence other than analogy with elliptic curves) that every K3 surface has infinitely many supersingular primes, and that for a random one such primes have density zero.

Comment: A necessary condition for this is that the characteristic polynomial of $\operatorname{Frob}_p$ has all roots $p$ times a root of unity. This is a sufficient condition for K3 surfaces under Artin's conjecture, as Piotr Achinger points out, and for arbitrary simply-connected surfaces under, I think, the Tate conjecture plus Shiodas conjecture. I, uh, have a short unpublished note about this condition, the upshot is (1) it has a rational density for any surface (or higher-dimensional algebraic variety), (2) this density is positive if and only if the variety has CM in a suitable sense.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger My intuition is that the "infinitely many supersingular primes" condition does not generalize from elliptic curves to most other types of varieties. The codimension of the moduli space of supersingular K3 surfaces inside the moduli space of all degree $d$ K3 surfaces is a lot higher than the codimension of the moduli space of supersingular elliptic curves among all elliptic curves, which turns out to matter for simple probabilistic heuristics. But there is certainly no proof.

Comment: @WillSawin where can I find this unpublished note? I would be very interested to see your thoughts on it.

Comment: I think an example where $S$ is empty is $E_1 \times E_2$ where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are elliptic curves whose sets of primes of bad reduction are disjoint.

Comment: This is a nice example! I guess if $X$ dominates a positive genus curve it puts serious constraints on $S_X$ i.e. it should be finite.

Comment: (1) More generally if $H_1(X, \mathbb Q)\neq 0$ then $H^1(X,\mathbb Q_\ell) \neq 0$ for all places of good reduction and thus $X$ is not unirational at any place of good reduction. It's not clear if unirationality at places of bad reduction is well-defined, but in any case that makes the set finite. (2) My note is not available anywhere, which is why I felt awkward citing it (the "uh"). If I get a chance I will look it over carefully and make it available...